# Days between two dates for multiple date ranges

Tags: sql, t-sql

Simple question:
How can I use this table :

```
Date    Start          End 
Date1   22-4-2017    6-5-2017
Date2   3-6-2017     17-6-2017
Date3   27-5-2017    2-6-2017
```

To get this output:

```
Date   Day  Date
Date1   1   22-4-2017
Date1   2   23-4-2017
Date1   3   24-4-2017
Date1   4   25-4-2017
Date1   5   26-4-2017
```

(till the last day and at the same time for date2 and date3)

Comment: I think you'll have to write a query of some sort.

Comment: Honeybadgers do care! Yeah I figured, was hoping someone could help me with a solution that doesn't need "Declare".

Comment: how data base ?

Comment: @RobJansen Which RDMS ?

Comment: You'll have to build a calendar table (google it, many examples online) and join it to the table.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti T-SQL

Comment: @RobJansen, T-SQL is a language, not an rdbms. Do you use SQL Server or Sybase? (I think those are the only ones that understand T-SQL.)

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2):

If SQL Server, you can use an ad-hoc tally table in concert with a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Select A.Date
      ,DayNo  = B.N
      ,Date2  = DateAdd(DAY,N-1,A.[Start])
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,[Start],[End])+1) 
                       N = Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null))
                 From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]